# flex:1 not working on table

Tags: html, css

Below is my table and i have applied background-image to second table row...and flex:1 to 2nd table row but my image is always invisible since it doesnt take proper height...i have applied flex so that it can take height...but after applying also it does not take height........

```
<table class="tablecontent">
  <tr>
       <td><span adsadsadsadsadsadsadsadsadAS
       </td>
 </tr>
 <tr style="flex: 1;">
       <td style="background-image: url(http://localhost:8083/Data/SF8-P64/data/SF8-P64/files/528FEAB5-F7B0-B822-C807-DEEE45312B6D.png); background-size: contain; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
       </td>
  </tr>
</table>
.tablecontent{height:100%;
width:100%
display:flex;
flex-direction:column}
```

Comment: background-image won't take height unless you give some content to the table cell or give padding or set explicit height and width

Answer (score 0):

@Shank

Your Right Table with right code...

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><span> adsadsadsadsadsadsadsadsadAS</span>
   </td>
</tr>
 <tr>
 <td height="100" style="background-image: url('http://localhost:8083/Data/SF8-P64/data/SF8-P64/files/528FEAB5-F7B0-B822-C807-DEEE45312B6D.png'); background-size: contain; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
       </td>
</tr>
</table>
```